# Node - Pushing array from JS to Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here's my app.js file:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.listen(3000);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const toSearch = []
    res.render('index', {toSearch});
})

app.use((req, res) => {
    res.status(404).render('404');
});
```

And here's a snippet of my JS file (on my index.js):

```
function addLatLng() {
  var name = document.getElementById('inputName').value();
  var lat = document.getElementById('latitude_input').value;
  var lng = document.getElementById('longitude_input').value;
  console.log('Name:'+name+'Latitude:' + lat + ', Longitude:' + lng);
}
```

I want to push the `name, lat. lng` data from my JS file into my app.js file. How do i achieve this? Im new to Node.js, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I understand: your JS file runs on the client. Your EJS runs on the server, before the client gets anything. So what do you want to _achieve_ here? (i.e. not what code do you want, but what task are you trying to achieve, and that you've written this code for)

Comment: with POST requests?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Sorry for the confusing question, what i want to do is insert  the data(name,lat,lng) from the js function to the ```toSearch``` array in my app.js

Comment: Look up ajax or fetch

Comment: I still don't understand: your app.js services literally an infinite number of users, whereas that JS file runs on a single user's computer. So what are you trying to _achieve_? Not "what do you want the code to do", what are you want to have happen? (e.g. "I want people to submit their location so I can store it for [...]" or the like. Ignore the tech: what are you trying to do, so that we can understand whether what you're asking lines up with that).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want here is a new express endpoint that can accept HTTP POST with a json body:

```js
    const toSearch = []
    app.use(express.json());
    app.post('/update', (req, res) => {
        let json = req.body;
    
        toSearch.push({
            name: json['name'],
            lat: json['lat'],
            lng: json['lng'],
        })
        console.log(toSearch)
    
        return res.send('toSearch updated');
    })
```

On the clientside, you're going to need some sort of code to send the POST request:

```js
      function addLatLng() {
        var name = document.getElementById('inputName').value;
        var lat = document.getElementById('latitude_input').value;
        var lng = document.getElementById('longitude_input').value;
        console.log('Name:' + name + 'Latitude:' + lat + ', Longitude:' + lng);

        var body = JSON.stringify({ name, lat, lng })
        fetch('/update', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: body
        }).then(res => console.log(res));
      }
```